# property loses value in IBAction

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am setting the parent property for a window and when I check the property in `windowDidLoad`, everything is good. But when I check it in `IBAction`, it is nil. What am I missing here?

AppController.m

```
loginController = [[LoginController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Login" owner:self];
loginController.parent = self;
[[loginController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

LoginController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) AppController *parent;
```

LoginController.m
    @synthesize parent;

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Parent: %@", self.parent); //<--- Parent: <AppController: 0xblahblah>
}

- (IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Parent: %@", self.parent); //<--- nil
}
```

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: If loginController isn't a weak property, then there is a retain cycle because AppController holds a strong pointer to LoginController and viceversa.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I had it as weak and switched it to the above to see if it made a difference.

Comment: And did you notice any difference?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I did not.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with my IB mappings? I read somewhere someone needed to set the button actions to the FileOwner, however this didn't work for me.

Comment: Probably you don't notice the retain cycle, it's not anything that throws an exception or causes a crash, but it's still a problem.

Comment: My guess is that you have two login controllers, which are two completely separated instances, and the action is triggered only on the other instance, which hasn't parent initialized. Do you have any instance of login controller in the xib file?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I did a search in the .xib file and returned no results.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the whole xib file seen from interface builder?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri OP has been edited

Comment: I got it, like I suspected you have two different login controller instances, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is just that you have set the wrong file owner, is login controller that holds the xib file, thus it has all the IBOutlets and IBActions bound.

Call initWithWindowNibName: instead of initWithWindowNibName:owner: , so that the file owner will be the newly created login controller, and not the app controller:

```
loginController = [[LoginController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Login"];
```

**Edit**

Like I suspected, you have two separate instances of login controller and you think to have only one. See the xib file:

[image]

That object "Login Controller" in the xib file, creates another instance of login controller. It's not the same instance that you allocate in app controller.

The solution is to make parent be an IBOutlet:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet AppController *parent;
```

And to don't allocate it in app controller, it will be load from the xib file automatically. **All you have to do is to bind it to the instance of login controller in the xib file** (if the file owner is app controller you should ctrl-drag the parent propert to the object icon, tell me if you meet some problem doing it). So that's why it prints null: the action is handled by another object, which hasn't the parent property initialized.

Comment: I took out `owner: self` and it is still `nil` in the `IBAction`

Comment: The second half of this answer is correct. You're making two instances of LoginController: one in the nib, and one in the app controller. Make one instance and share it with the other objects which need it.

Comment: This case the first part of the question doesn't apply.

Comment: You are a life saver. I was only following a tutorial where they said to create an object and map. I removed LoginController object and mapped everything to the File's Owner. It seems to work. Will this be good or will it cause issues down the road?

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidLoad you access an iVar called `parent`. 
In login: you access the property `self.parent`. 
That can be the same or it can be different.

Did you `@synthesize` the property? If so, without any additional options? Then you should be fine. parent and `self.parent` should be the same thing.

Did you autosynthesize it? That is ok. But then the corresponding iVar is called `_parent`. Meaning then you must have an additional ivar `parent` which is not the same ivar.

Add all the declarations to your question for more details.